# Combining two mysql table results on drop down option and retrieve selected

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a drop list that will retrieve the value from table (data_builder) and want to combine existing suburb from another table (data_suburb). so when I click on the dropdown list it will display the selected Suburb and all the Suburbs from data_suburb

Example I Have:

TABLE (data_builder)

```
<b>id | builder_name | builder_suburb | builder_state | builder_postcode</b><br>

   1  | Biz Shop     | Richmond       | VIC           | 3121<br>
   2  | Tony Sykes   | Melbourne      | VIC           | 3000<br>
   3  | HDI Group    | Abbotsford     | VIC           | 3607<br>
```

etc...

TABLE (data_suburb)

```
<b>id | suburb       | suburb_state  | suburb_postcode</b><br>

   1  | Abbotsford   | VIC           | 3067<br>
   2  | Aberfeldie   | VIC           | 3040<br>
   3  | Aberfeldy    | VIC           | 3825<br>
```

etc...

Here my code I tried

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/conn.php";
$id =$_REQUEST['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data_builder WHERE id  = '$id'");
$retrieve = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$BuildSuburb=$retrieve['builder_suburb'] ;

echo "<select name='buildersuburb'>";
      $query="SELECT suburb FROM data_suburbs ORDER BY suburb ASC";
      $result = mysql_query($query);


            if(!$result){

                die ("Could not query the database: <br />" . mysql_error());

            }

while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
             echo '<option value="' . $data[suburb];
             if($data[suburb]=$BuildSuburb): echo $data[suburb] . '"' .     'selected="selected"';
             else: echo $data[suburb] . '"';
             endif;
             echo '" >' . $data[suburb] . '</option>'. "\n";

}




echo "</select>";
```

Comment: what was the result of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following Line in while loop $data=mysql_fetch_array($result) to

$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) because you are using $data['suburb']

Also in your $query there is no need for ASC